# Write to file in random order from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedwriter

I have 20 threads running in parallel. Each makes a call to function, fetches 200 records and writes to a file. I want to randomize all the records. Is there any way in which I can write to a file in such a way that I get 10 records from one thread and then 10 from next and so on ?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Why does it need to be multi threaded as opposed to a single thread which randomizes the list before writing?

Comment: @MatejKormuth I am thinking of the approach with the existing code....which falls under NDA

Comment: @twm That is needed coz there are millions of records and it would take a lot of time if executed serially.

Comment: @MadhavPatekar, how about posting a bare bones, runnable stub that reflects what's needed for the question, but which is written from scratch in order to avoid the NDA?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way in which I can write to a file in such a way that I get 10 records from one thread and then 10 from next and so on?

If I understood correctly, your problem is how to coordinate the output of multiple threads so each thread prints its output in certain order.

in this case, I would use a "Queue" to coordinate the work of the threads. Something like a ticketing system. If the head of the queue corresponds to the thread id/name, then that thread can print its output (and when it is done, it removes its name from the head of the queue).

A separate Coordinator would be deciding in which order threads are allowed to print their output.

for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * 
 */
public class SchedulerExample {

    public static final int BATCH_LINES = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SchedulerExample schedulerExample = new SchedulerExample();
        schedulerExample.doTheWork();
    }

    private void doTheWork() throws InterruptedException {


        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        List<String> allowedWorkersNames = new ArrayList<>();
        allowedWorkersNames.add("worker1");
        allowedWorkersNames.add("worker2");
        allowedWorkersNames.add("worker3");

        executorService.submit(new Coordinator(allowedWorkersNames, queue));
        executorService.submit(new Worker("worker1", queue, BATCH_LINES));
        executorService.submit(new Worker("worker2", queue, BATCH_LINES));
        executorService.submit(new Worker("worker3", queue, BATCH_LINES));

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        System.out.println("ending application");
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}

/**
 * this class decides the order in which workers are allowed to print their outputs
 */
class Coordinator implements Callable<Void> {
    private List<String> allowedWorkersNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private Queue<String> queue;

    public Coordinator(List<String> allowedWorkersNames, Queue<String> queue) {
        this.allowedWorkersNames = allowedWorkersNames;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            if (queue.size() == 0) {
                queue.addAll(allowedWorkersNames);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {

    private String name;
    private int linesCounter;
    private Queue<String> queue;
    private int batchLines;

    public Worker(String name, Queue<String> queue, int batchLines) {
        this.name = name;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.batchLines = batchLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            // do some useful work here.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(name + "was interrupted");
            }

            // now this thread is ready to print its output.
            String currentHeadOfQueue = queue.peek();
            if (currentHeadOfQueue != null && currentHeadOfQueue.compareTo(name) == 0) {


                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, batchLines).
                        forEach(i -> {
                                    linesCounter++;
                                    System.out.println(name + " - line:" + linesCounter);
                                }
                        );

                queue.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```